# Project Euler: #2 in Python

Tags: python, fibonacci

The problem presented is as follows:

```
Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.
```

I have tried a few variations on the code you see below. I am currently getting the number 2,435,424 as the answer from the code I have written, however Project Euler is saying that number is incorrect. I have tried changing looking in to reasons my code is failing, and I'm stumped. Any advice would be appreciated. Code is as follows:

```
fibonacci = [2]

i = 0

number_1 = 1
number_2 = 2
number_3 = 0

while (number_3 <= 4000000):
    number_3 = number_1 + number_2
    fibonacci.append(number_3)

    if i % 2 != 0:
        number_1 = number_3
        i += 1
    elif i % 2 == 0:
        number_2 = number_3
        i += 1

total = 0

for numbers in fibonacci:
    if numbers % 2 == 0:
        total += numbers

print total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replace number_2 on the first iteration. That is not correct.

There is no need to evaluate an extra if in this case! an integer %2 is either 0 or 1, so use else.
On top of that using if/else doesn't make much sense here, you could just do a rotation instead. Try doing it by hand and you'll see.

Project Euler is more about learning to find the solution with good code and shortcuts (4 million was originally a lot and couldn't be acquired through a bad recursion that goes through both branches). So **I will not include the exact solution to any Project Euler question here** but point you into the right direction instead.
I highly suggest learning about python generators (see dawg's answer), since this is the easiest example to learn and understand them.

Also, it would be best to keep the running total inside your main loop so you don't have to go through them again.

Note regarding Project Euler: Python is not restricted with respect to integers (you can have infinite precision if you want) so some of the questions will not make as much sense. Also, RAM and CPU have increased exponentially; so consider doing this problem with 4 billion instead of 4 million and you will learn much more. That's where a useless elif could be expensive, and looping over something twice even worse because you have to keep track of the whole structure.
Think of it this way: can you **solve the problem without keeping more than the bare-necessary variables** in memory? That's where generators, xrange, etc come in very handy (python 2.x).

Comment: Thanks. I agree. I had originally kept running total in my main section, but when I ran in to issues with the answer not being correct broke it out since I realized that part of the code was correct and could not have been part of my problem. Now that the issue is fixed, I will clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [many ways](http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_(Python)) you can write a Fibonacci sequence in Python.

The most 'Pythonic', IMHO, is a [generator](http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_(Python)#chunk%20use:fibonacci_generator.py):

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while 1:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

You can modify that with the limit and the test of `a % 2`:

```
def Fib_in_even(lim):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < lim:
        if not a % 2:         
            yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

Then use `sum` to add up the modified Fibonacci series to 'the answer':

```
>>> sum(Fib_in_even(4000000))  
the_answer...
```

Comment: good answer :) .. pretty simillar to mine but a little cleaner I think

Comment: Good answer. Thanks for the links, very helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, your loop appends one value too many to your list. Consider what happens if `number_3` equals 4 million. Your loop will then compute a new value of `number_3`, which will exceed 4 million because one of `number_1` or `number_2` will have just been set equal to `number_3`, and add it to your list. The same holds true for any `number_3` such that `number_3 <= 4000000` but `number_3 + min(number_1, number_2) > 4000000`, I'm just using 4 million as a value that easily demonstrates the error.

I make no comment on the general algorithm - working on that is part of the point of Project Euler. But it's worth considering what you might do if the end value were not 4 million, but something too large to keep all the Fibonacci terms in memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing doing the sum that project euler is asking for and the actual calculation of the fibonacci numbers. In the process of mixing this, you mess up both halves.

Let's do it one at a time:

```
fibonacci = [1, 2]
number_1 = 1
number_2 = 2
number_3 = 3

while (number_3 <= 4000000):
    number_1, number_2, number_3 = number_2, number_3, number_1 + number_2
    fibonacci.append(number_3)
```

Now, we have a list of fibonacci numbers. Let's sum the even ones.

```
total = 0
for numbers in fibonacci:
    if numbers % 2 == 0:
        total += numbers
```

Or more simply:

```
total = sum(x for x in fibonacci if x % 2 == 0)
```

And you'll absolutely want to apply the advice in [Peter DeGlopper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26026527/47453).

Comment: This has an error, number_2 will first be updated to 0 in your current code.

Comment: There was nothing incorrect with my sum of the fibonacci numbers, just in the construction of the fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
def FibSeries(first,second):
    yield first
    while True:
        first,second = second,first+second
        yield first

fib_lt_4mil = itertools.takewhile(lambda n:n<4000000,FibSeries(1,1))
even_fib_lt_4mil = [n for n in fib_lt_4mil if n%2 == 0]
print sum(even_fib_lt4mil)
```

at least I think

Comment: Yes, that answer is correct, but I was trying to adjust the code that I had existing, not start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
def EvenFibonacciNumbersSum(n):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    temp = 0
    sum =0
    while(a<=n):
        if(a%2 ==0):
            sum = sum + a
        #print(sum)
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp+b
    return sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(EvenFibonacciNumbersSum(4000000))
```